# How To Implement Rich Text Editor

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rich-text-editor

I want to implement rich text editor in my project, the situation is when user click the file,the file will open in the text editor.I use vb.net and asp.net. someone have idea please help me..

Comment: Have you looked into any of the existing rich text editors available?  Are you dealing with a specific file format?  In general I imagine you would use an off-the-shelf rich text editor (there are many available) and just set its content to the content of the file, let the user edit, and then replace the file contents with the editor contents on save.  Have you begun any attempt at this?

Comment: I have looking for this,but i can't find the code to implement the rich text editor.I want all file format can read by my rich text editor.But for off-the-shelf I not try this yet.I will use your advice sir.Thank You

Comment: Check out [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Comment: Good information on Implementing Rich Text Editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample:

[Rich Text Editor with ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/455129/Rich-Text-Editor-with-ASP-NET)

[An Example to Use HTML Rich Text Editor - Cleditor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/254007/An-Example-to-Use-HTML-Rich-Text-Editor-Cleditor)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Firstly download the ckeditor from
```

> https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/

then copy the ckeditor folder and paste it in your asp.net website.

---

```
 Add the script <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> in the header 
 section '<head></head>'.

 Make sure that in <%@ %> part ValidateRequest is set false . In .NET 4 you 
 may need to do a little more. Sometimes it's necessary to also add 
 
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /> 

  to web.config.
```

---

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" 
 ValidateRequest="false" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>
 <asp:TextBox ID="text" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
 <script>
   CKEDITOR.replace("text"); 
 </script> 

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="save" OnClick="save"  />
     <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="show" OnClick="showData"  />
   
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
   
 </div>
 </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
In aspx.cs file.
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Label1.Text = "";
      cn.ConnectionString = "ConnectionString";
   }
   protected void save(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      cn.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO new (data) values (@data)" , cn);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data",text.Text);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      text.Text = "";
      cn.Close();

    }

     protected void showData(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT data from new where id = 14", cn);
        Label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        cn.Close();
      }
   }
```